# fatal error COM class not found in linux

Tags: php, linux, fatal-error

COM class is accesible in windows but isn't in linux .can you help me plz ?

```
      <?php
       if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
       $Browserhandle = $Browser->HWND;
       $Browser->Visible = true;
       $Browser->Fullscreen = true;
       $Browser->Navigate($_POST['url']);

       while($Browser->Busy){
       com_message_pump(10000);
       }
       $img = imagegrabwindow($Browserhandle, 0);
       $Browser->Quit();
       imagepng($img, 'screenshot.png');
       }

      ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, COM is a Windows-only extension.

http://php.net/manual/en/com.requirements.php

Comment: so which class is uesd instead of COM class in linux

Comment: None, there's no alternative.

Comment: so how cane we get screen shot in linux from url